# pancakeswap: I can't check balance on a specific address using web3

Tags: python

I am using the code below and I got the following error message and I don't know why. I tried to find out myself but could not figure out.

"BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?"

```
from web3 import Web3
bsc = 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))


sender_address = '0x19d415204c7F10c1396866aC00C47d3067433534'
sender_address = web3.toChecksumAddress(sender_address)
cake_address = '0x0e09Fabb73bd3dde0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82'
cake_address = web3.toChecksumAddress(cake_address)

sellAbi = '[{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"delegator","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"fromDelegate","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"toDelegate","type":"address"}],"name":"DelegateChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"previousBalance","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"newBalance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DelegateVotesChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DELEGATION_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"","type":"uint32"}],"name":"checkpoints","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"fromBlock","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"votes","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"delegatee","type":"address"}],"name":"delegate","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"delegatee","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"expiry","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"delegateBySig","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"delegator","type":"address"}],"name":"delegates","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"getCurrentVotes","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"blockNumber","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getPriorVotes","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"nonces","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"numCheckpoints","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"","type":"uint32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'

sellTokenContract = web3.eth.contract(cake_address,abi=sellAbi)

balance = sellTokenContract.functions.balanceOf(sender_address).call()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I found the answer, cake_address was wrong. It was ''